# OrientDB include property from connected vertex

Tags: orientdb

My Current Query:

```
SELECT *, in('Provides').include('id') as provider FROM #12:1
```

This gives the full record of #12:1 plus one more property provider (as expected).

However, provider contains:

```
[{"@type":"d","@version":0,"id":"providerId"}]
```

I would like it to contain:

```
"providerId"
```

to not have to "clean up" the property, is it possible?

**Background** *(if my approach is wrong)*

I have 2 vertices connected by a 'Provides' edge.

V1 ----Provides----> V2

I want to query for whole V1 but add V2's id property as provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create this schema to try your case:

[image]

try this query:

```
SELECT *, in('Provides').id[id] as provider FROM #12:1
```

this is the output:

[image]

if you don't like seeing the 'providerId' between brackets you can use unwind:

```
SELECT *, in('Provides').id[id] as provider FROM #12:1 unwind provider
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think it should be SELECT *, in('Provides').include('id')[id] as provider from #12:1, that works great for me! The unwind was nice as well. Thanks a lot!